# Excel Add In - Where does console.log output it's message - NodeJS

Tags: jquery, node.js, excel, excel-addins, office-2016

I am trying to create an Excel AddIn with JavaScript API. But I don't understand where "console.log" outputs their messages. All Microsoft documentations are full with console.log examples, but it is not explained where console.log() outputs the messages. I have found a similar post on stackoverflow, but these refer to visual studio console log. I am writing my AddIn with nodeJs on Mac, so a solution for visual studio is no option for me.

I have searched the web. I have searched through all Excel options. I have also searched through the Excel Developer tab, but I can't find anything.

I am using Office 2016 (up to date) on Mac. My AddIn is coded with jQuery.

Has anyone an idea?

## EDIT

I have created my ExcelAddin in NodeJS. Therefore I have installed yo and office-generator `npm install -g yo generator-office`
. Then I have ran the command `yo office` and selected jQuery as library. The sample AddIn works.

Comment: Did you manage to make it work?

Comment: I'm afraid not. There is no documentation at all.

Comment: I just found the solution. You can install the Microsoft Edge DevTools Preview via the Microsoft Store now. There you can attach to the console output.

Comment: [Łukasz Zadworny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15062168) wrote an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66079730) saying "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/debug-add-ins-using-f12-developer-tools-on-windows-10 this is solution to problem..."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

defaults write com.microsoft.Excel OfficeWebAddinDeveloperExtras -bool true

After entering that ^ in a terminal, when you right click your add-in, you'll have the option to Inspect Element (aka Safari Web Inspector). The console tab will show all the logged messages from console.log() statments.

Comment: Thanks. How did you find this solution?

Comment: This solution can be found in the **Debug Office Add-ins on a Mac** documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/debug-office-add-ins-on-ipad-and-mac