# How can I display console.log?

Tags: javascript, excel-addins, javascript-api-for-office

this topic is related to persons who developing excel add-ins using javascript api.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-ranges#get-the-selected-range

How can I display message via `` console.log(`The address of the selected range is "${range.address}"`); `` in VSCODE console or debug console?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run JavaScript in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31778413/run-javascript-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: You will need to run the add-in in Excel itself.

Comment: you could try using node

Comment: hi upper buddies, NOPE, your answers are incorrect...

Comment: Assuming that you have installed Nodejs, then simply open your terminal inside VSCode and type `node your_file_name`. If this not what you are looking for, please make your question more clear.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Excel Add In - Where does console.log output it's message - NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50434202/excel-add-in-where-does-console-log-output-its-message-nodejs), and also see: [Debug Office Add-ins on a Mac](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/debug-office-add-ins-on-ipad-and-mac)

Answer (score 0):

This is solution to my problem:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/debug-add-ins-using-f12-developer-tools-on-windows-10

Answer (score 0):

On a Mac, open safari develop menu (you may need to adjust settings to see it) and open the menu with the hostname of your Mac.  Look for Excel related pages to debug.  This will open safari dev tools which has a console log.